# Using <ContextProvider> inside of <Switch>

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

1- I want to wrap "Model" component with "ModelStateProvider" like below but it does not work. I searched Google and couldn't find any practical solution. I would like to know if there is a way to make it work.

2- I wonder if it would be practical and efficient to wrap the whole app with "ModelStateProvider" like "AuthStateProvider" but keep that in mind I will be consuming "ModelStateProvider" only with "Model" component.

Can you help me to get some idea please?

Thank you :]

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthStateProvider>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <main className='container'>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
            <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
            <ModelStateProvider>
              <Route exact path='/model/:link' component={Model} />
            </ModelStateProvider>
            <Route exact path='/models' component={Models} />
            <Route exact path='/profiles' component={Profiles} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/account' component={Account} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/publish' component={Publish} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </AuthStateProvider>
  )
}
```

**EDIT:**
Rendering it inside of the Route fixed it. Since I needed the path, I passed it as props. You can see the solution below.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/model/:link'
  render={(path) => (
    <ModelStateProvider>
      <Model path={path} />
    </ModelStateProvider>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: What about this does not work? What's the error? What does `Model` and `ModelStateProvider` look like?

Comment: It is not possible to wrap a <Route> that is within <Switch>. I think the error is obvious. You can only put <Route> and <Redirect> in <Switch>... So, I am trying to find a way to overcome this.

Comment: The error is probably obvious to you but isn't obvious to anyone without the context of your problem. When I ask "what's the error?" I mean "what is the specific error output you are seeing?" because it is probably useful in figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: It does not output an error. It is just not possible to make it work like that. If you make a little bit of research about using <Switch>, you will find out that you can't wrap a route with <ContextProvider>. That is the nature of React itself. Basically, what I want to achieve is to wrap a <Route> with <ContextProvider>. What I tried in the example code, makes other routes not work.

Comment: > That is the nature of React itself. 

This is misleading at best, and probably incorrect. The routing library you are using enforces this constraint, not React. The documentation for said routing library provides an example that covers your case, which I found with a little bit of research.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a `component` prop to the route, you could use the implicit `children` prop, which is what [the documentation for Switch shows in the example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node).

```js
<Switch>
  <Route … />
  <Route exact path='/model/:link'>
    <ModelStateProvider>
      <Model />
    </ModelStateProvider>
  </Route>
  …
</Switch>
```

If that doesn't satisfy your constraints for routing or route matching, or if you can't pass all router props to the immediate children of the provider for some reason, you could make a composite component that wraps the provider and model:

```js
const ModelWithProvider = (props) => (
  <ModelStateProvider>
    <Model {...props} />
  </ModelStateProvider>
);

// …
<Switch>
  <Route … />
  <Route exact path='/model/:link' component={ModelWithProvider} />
  …
</Switch>
```

And if *that* doesn't work or isn't possible to wrap ahead of time for some reason, you could just wrap the `Switch` (or `Router`, or whatever ancestor you want) with `ModelStateProvider`. You alluded to this in your question but you didn't explain why or how that doesn't work for you other than "efficiency." Is there anything flagrantly inefficient about your app when you tried that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is the solution I was looking for and sorry for not being clear enough. I thought the problem would be solved easily and you guys would understand the problem at first sight. But this solution gives me another error. The Model component can't reach "path='/model/:link'". Error: const link = props.match.params.link is undefined.

Comment: If you used the first solution, you'll need to pass on all props from the provider to its immediate children, which probably won't scale to a general purpose provider but probably does work for your specific use case here.

Comment: First I tried to pass props following the second solution that you provided but then found a cleaner way to pass props down to <Model> while it is simply wrapped with <ModelStateProvider>. Thank you for your interest!